# chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher conditions not

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm starting to learn how to develop a chrome extention (manifest 3) and I have some result I don't understand.
My final goal is to get the cookie value when a specific website is open, to send a request to this web site (fetch) and to show the json received in a new tab (I developed a javascript to send the request and it's working but I now want to get the cookie automaticaly with a chrome extention).

To start my learning, first step is to open a new tab when I'm on the website. I tried the below code in my background.js but the new tab is created when I activate my extention even if the website is not open and no new tab created after even if my condition is ok. Then I think I missed something but I don't knwo what.

Could someone explain me why, where I'm wrong and if not the good way, which chrome API I should see ?

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function () {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostEquals: "www.google.com", schemes: ["https"] },
          }),
        ],
        actions: [chrome.tabs.create({})],
      },
    ]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `actions: [chrome.tabs.create({})]` is wrong. The method `chrome.tabs.create` will be called when the extension installed. Maybe you want to trigger your popup.html when clicking the extension. If so, you can use `actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]`. Then use `chrome.action.onClicked.addListener`, [see here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#event-onClicked).

If you want to automatically open a new tab when some website is opened, you can use `chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener`, [see here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onCreated), handle the event, filter the url, then do sth.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me to search in the correct direction. I used `chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener` `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`  and `chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener`